# Setup Windows 8.1 802.1x MS-CHAPv2 and freeradius issue

Tags: windows, centos7, freeradius

I cannot authenticate my Windows Laptop using MS-CHAPv2 and Freeradius.

This is the error message I get:

```
(7) eap_mschapv2: # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
(7) eap_mschapv2:   authenticate {
(7) mschap: WARNING: No Cleartext-Password configured.  Cannot create NT-Password
(7) mschap: WARNING: No Cleartext-Password configured.  Cannot create LM-Password
(7) mschap: Creating challenge hash with username: maksim
(7) mschap: Client is using MS-CHAPv2
(7) mschap: ERROR: FAILED: No NT/LM-Password.  Cannot perform authentication
(7) mschap: ERROR: MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect
(7)     [mschap] = reject
(7)   } # authenticate = reject
(7) eap: Sending EAP Failure (code 4) ID 8 length 4
(7) eap: Freeing handler
(7)       [eap] = reject
(7)     } # authenticate = reject
(7)   Failed to authenticate the user
(7)   Login incorrect (mschap: FAILED: No NT/LM-Password.  Cannot perform authentication): [maksim] (from client dlink port 0 via TLS tunnel)
```

It says that I don't have Cleartext-Password configured, but I don't agree:

```
MariaDB [radius]> select * from radcheck;
+----+----------+--------------------+----+----------+
| id | username | attribute          | op | value    |
+----+----------+--------------------+----+----------+
|  9 | maksim   | User-Password      | := | 1q2w3e4r |
|  8 | maksim   | Cleartext-Password | := | 1q2w3e4r |
| 10 | maksim   | Auth-Type          | := | MS-CHAP  |
| 11 | maksim   | CHAP-Password      | := | 1q2w3e4r |
| 12 | maksim   | NT-Password        | := | 1q2w3e4r |
+----+----------+--------------------+----+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing

```
driver = "rlm_sql_null"
```

to

```
driver = "rlm_sql_mysql"
```

in

```
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/sql
```